# Derivation of the law of the conditional using the disjunct form

Tags: logic, formal-theory

How can we prove that

> **P ⊃ Q**

is logicaly equivalent to

> **¬P ∨ Q**

using the laws of derivation?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

For **¬P ∨ Q ⊢ P → Q** :

1) **¬P ∨ Q** --- premise : apply [Disjunction Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination)

2) **Q** --- assumed [a]

3) **P → Q** --- by **→**-Introduction

4) **¬P** --- assumed [b]

5) **P** --- assumed [c]

6) **contradiction**

7) **Q** --- from 6)

8) **P → Q** --- by **→**-Introduction, discharging [c]

Having derived **P → Q** under both assumptions [a] and [b], we may discharge them by Disjunction Elimination and conclude from 1) with :

> 9) **P → Q**.

The other "direction" needs [Double Negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation) : for details, see the post : [proof that p implies q entails not p or q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002811/proof-that-p-implies-q-entails-not-p-or-q).